# How to calculate Bayes error rate in R for a data has two classes ?

Tags: r

I have this data that has two classes and 5000 observations, I generated this data as follow:

```
# sample from beta dist.  and normal 
betadata1 <- function(seed,n.obs,boun1,boun2,k1,k2,k3,s1,s2,s3 ) {
  set.seed(seed)
  U =runif(n.obs)                                          
  rand.samples = rep(NA,n.obs)
  for(i in 1:n.obs){
    if(U[i]< boun1){
      rand.samples[i] = rbeta(1,k1,s1)
    }else if(U[i]< boun2){
      rand.samples[i] = rbeta(1,k2,s2)
    }else{
      rand.samples[i] = rbeta(1,k3,s3)
    }
  }
  class = rep( 1, n.obs )
  data  = data.frame( V1 = class,V2 = rand.samples )
}
betadata2 <- function(seed, n.obs,k1,s1 ) {
  set.seed(seed)
  #Sample N random uniforms U
  U =runif( n.obs)                                            
  rand.samples = rep(NA, n.obs)
  for(i in 1: n.obs){
    rand.samples[i] = rnorm(1,k1,s1)
  }
  class = rep( 2, n.obs )
  data  = data.frame( V1 = class,V2 = rand.samples )
}
############ 
mix.data1 = betadata1(893123,3500,1,1,.2,20,25,.2,1,1) 
mix.data2= betadata2(1170022,1500,.5,.2)
data.gen.training = rbind(mix.data1,mix.data2)
mix.data11 = betadata1(102938,840,1,1,.2,20,25,.2,1,1)
mix.data22= betadata2(910710999,360,.5,.2)
data.gen.test = rbind(mix.data11,mix.data22)
```

My question is how to calculate the bayes error rate for this data as in the following plot? [The two classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULCwu.jpg)

Comment: Any help or idea  would be much appreciated